# Visual solution requested regarding image within div

Tags: css

I have the following images:

[image]

The problem is that this looks like crap.
What is the most common (CSS) solution to make a better visual fit?
I will try to code it myself, but offered code is also welcome.

I want to allow organisers to upload any size (but within a max filesize).
The reason is that the user can click the image to maximise it on original size, so I don't want to limit the possibility to upload any size (width / height).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Option 1

This option will result in some wonky images, but users will see 100% of the image and each one will be the same size.

```
.image-wrap {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.image-wrap img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
```

### Option 2

This option will result in variable height boxes depending on the height of the image, but no image distortion - all boxes will be the same width.

```
.image-wrap {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
}

.image-wrap img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

### Option 3

This option will attempt to show a cropped view of a middle portion of the image.  This assumes that users will be uploading images which are not very long on any dimension.  If your users can upload very wide but short images this won't work.  Also, a portion of the image will be cropped out... always.

```
.image-wrap {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image-wrap img {
    width: 140%;
    margin-left: -20%;
    margin-top: -10%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll take my chances on option 2. Tried option 1, but that turned into a visual nightmare.

Comment: Yeah, sizing images is difficult.  The only way to handle different sized images in the *best* way is with javascript.  It also helps if you can know the width and height of the images on the server and embed the dimensions in markup.  If you can do this, use the "width" and "height" attributes (not the style attribute): `<img width="200" height="200" ...>`

Comment: Ok, that's another thing to look into. Thanks for advice.